# Google Cloud Run Port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Container Contract says, cloud run should listen to the port defined by `PORT` environment variable. The environment variable is set to `8080`. My question is can we change this variable to different port?

[link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#env-vars)

Answer (score 7):

Cloud Run recently added support for changing the default port.

You can try "gcloud alpha run deploy ... --port=" or via the Cloud Console UI to deploy.

Answer (score 5):

From **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port):**

> The container must listen for requests on 0.0.0.0 on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.
>
> In Cloud Run container instances, the `PORT` environment variable is always set to 8080, but for portability reasons, your code **should not** hardcode this value.

Your existing applications must listen on PORT environment variable to work on Cloud Run, as specified on the documentation.

Comment: Right, I get the hard code part. My question was in the WEB UI console there is an option to provide a port number that container should listen to why creating a service in Cloud Run. Will this value override the PORT number of Environment variable?

Comment: Yes, PORT env var will be overridden

Answer (score 4):

If you build your container with a `Dockerfile`, you can specify the PORT environment variable with

`ENV PORT {Number}`

Here's an example `Dockerfile`:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

ENV PORT 443

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it not because the port, it error on npm script on server [image]

I got the same "Missing Port" error. You can find the logs when you click on the cloud run service.

Answer (score -1):

The `PORT` environment variable *tells* you which port your server *must* listen on internally, the 8080 value is just an example. You cannot change it yourself. This is unrelated to the port visible from the outside that your clients connect to.

Comment: In the webUI while creating a Cloud Run there is an option to specify the container port. So I am assuming the port number can be changed.